# What actually happens when using char toUpperCase

Tags: java

I'd like to make sure I *actually understand* what is happening when I use .toUpperCase
This is a piece of code that's working fine. I'd just like to know if my comments correctly describe what is happening.

```
char first = 'j';   //Declare char variable & initialize it's value: j

/* toUpperCase method of the Character Class Wrapper is invoked
 * char primitives are autoboxed to Character Objects
 * toUpperCase method unboxes the converted Characters to char primitives
 */

char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(first);
```

*Thanks to everyone for responding with both simple and highly detailed answers. Much appreciated.*

Answer (score 2):

No.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html.  The signature of `toUpperCase` is

```
public static char toUpperCase(char ch)
```

in other words a `char` goes in and a `char` comes out.  In your example, no autoboxing or autounboxing occurs at all.

Answer (score 1):

As addition to the other answers, the source code:

Character.java

```
public static char toUpperCase(char ch) {
    return (char)toUpperCase((int)ch);
}

public static int toUpperCase(int codePoint) {
    return CharacterData.of(codePoint).toUpperCase(codePoint);
}
```

CharacterData.java

```
static final CharacterData of(int ch) {
    if (ch >>> 8 == 0) {     // fast-path
        return CharacterDataLatin1.instance;
    } else {
        switch(ch >>> 16) {  //plane 00-16
        case(0):
            return CharacterData00.instance;
        case(1):
            return CharacterData01.instance;
        case(2):
            return CharacterData02.instance;
        case(14):
            return CharacterData0E.instance;
        case(15):   // Private Use
        case(16):   // Private Use
            return CharacterDataPrivateUse.instance;
        default:
            return CharacterDataUndefined.instance;
        }
    }
}
```

CharacterData00.java (for example)

```
int toUpperCase(int ch) {
    int mapChar = ch;
    int val = getProperties(ch);

    if ((val & 0x00010000) != 0) {
      if ((val & 0x07FC0000) == 0x07FC0000) {
        switch(ch) {
          // map chars with overflow offsets
        case 0x00B5 : mapChar = 0x039C; break;
        case 0x017F : mapChar = 0x0053; break;
        case 0x1FBE : mapChar = 0x0399; break;
          // map char that have both a 1:1 and 1:M map
        case 0x1F80 : mapChar = 0x1F88; break;
        case 0x1F81 : mapChar = 0x1F89; break;
        case 0x1F82 : mapChar = 0x1F8A; break;
        case 0x1F83 : mapChar = 0x1F8B; break;
        case 0x1F84 : mapChar = 0x1F8C; break;
        case 0x1F85 : mapChar = 0x1F8D; break;
        case 0x1F86 : mapChar = 0x1F8E; break;
        // Many more
       }
      }
      else {
        int offset = val  << 5 >> (5+18);
        mapChar =  ch - offset;
      }
    }
    return mapChar;
}
```

As you can see: at no point boxing/unboxing occurrs.

Answer (score 0):

Internally `toUpperCase` uses `CharacterData` and it's subclasses (package private) to find the mapping from a lowercase character to its uppercase counterpart.

In fact most of the internal operations are done using `int` variables. No wrapper types are involved in the conversion.